# Where are the API for short range communication with iOs?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, api, bluetooth, dock

I want to develop an IOS program that will communicate with internet and also communicate with nearby stuffs. Basically we want to notify the iPhone of cars plate numbers that's coming in.

I understand how iPhone can communicate with internet. But what about if we want faster communication that's near?

I know there is this "dock". Then there is wifi, then near field communication, and bluetooth.

To communicate with the web we need only to use 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

What about if we want to use nearer communications?

What class should we use?

Note: I've heard iPhone close their dock API unless for special periperhal factory. Buying additional periperhal is fine as long as we got the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you are looking for a technology like Bonjour?

https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/

I believe Bonjour works for both Blue Tooth as well as wifi within a shared router.

Comment: +1. I will select his as the answer in a few days. So bonjour can communicate with  shared router and bluetooth. Very good.